# Animated gif in panel's "BackgroundImage" property (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, animated-gif

Panel's "**BackgroundImage**" property accepts *.gif format (in winform designer) but when I assign a gif, it doesn't animate! is there any way to put animated gif in panel background?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @HansPassant
Thanks. I'll try. I thought it would be a simpler way because in the designer environment it accepts *.gif format...

Comment: Why don't you use a PictureBox instead of a Panel? It can animate without any intervention.

Comment: @Jimi
because i have a SplitContainer (that has two panels) and i want to show animated gif on one of panels

Comment: Well, what about docking a PictureBox inside it? Or even without docking it, if you don't want it to stretch / resize. Panels are not even double-buffered, so you'd need a custom Panel or use reflection to double-buffer it, but not with the same effect you have simply using a PictureBox.

Comment: @Jimi
Yes. This can also be a solution. I wanted to not change the design as much as possible, but if there is no other way, I will do the same.